# Why do Belgian supermarkets not provide price per kg in price labels?

Tags: legal, eu, price, belgium, fraud

In most supermarkets and shops in Europe I'm used to see price labels like [this](https://conversation.which.co.uk/food-drink/supermarket-unit-pricing-event-price-it-right-sainsburys-morrisons/):
[image: SUpermarket price label]

The only part I usually look at is the price per kg. I thought it was an EU standard, I'm pretty sure it's mandatory in some countries.

In Belgium I noticed that the price tags are extremely obscure, full of weird codes and values (e.g. in Carrefour). Why is that? Is there a way to defend oneself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about travel, but about general consumer knowledge.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you added an example of a label that the question is about (i.e. without price/unit) instead of one that the question is not about. Normally the price per unit should be there: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/unfair-treatment/unfair-pricing/index_en.htm I would say that in general they do provide a price per unit.